# use apply_filters return taxonomies custom post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, hooks

I reused the following code where a specific taxonomy is registered:

```
public static function get_taxonomies_to_register() {
    $taxonomies = apply_filters( 'wp_taxonomies', array(

        'wp_course' => array(
            'name'               => _x( 'Courses', 'taxonomy general name', 'test' ),
            'singular_name'      => _x( 'Course', 'taxonomy singular name', 'test' ),
        ),

        'wp_kind' => array(
            'name'               => _x( 'kinds', 'taxonomy general name', 'test' ),
            'singular_name'      => _x( 'kind', 'taxonomy singular name', 'test' ),
        ),

    ));

    return $taxonomies;
}
```

I want to dynamically register all taxonomies of my custom post type, so I used the following code:

```
function get_new_taxonomies ( $taxonomies) {

    return get_object_taxonomies('my_custom_post_type'); ;
}

add_filter('wp_taxonomies', get_new_taxonomies );

$wp_taxonomies_result = WP_Taxonomies::get_taxonomies();
```

But i got only two taxonomies: Course and Kind. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand. `get_object_taxonomies()` returns taxonomies that have been registered. Why would you want to register them again?

Comment: i just try to use plugin who create custom post type with specific taxonomy and i try to add taxonomies of another custom post type to the custom post type created by the plugin , i don't know if i'm clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the existing taxonomies to the array you're returning.  try this:

```
function get_new_taxonomies ( $taxonomies) {

        return array_merge($taxonomies, get_object_taxonomies('my_custom_post_type'));
    }
add_filter('wp_taxonomies', get_new_taxonomies );

$wp_taxonomies_result = WP_Taxonomies::get_taxonomies();
```

Comment: i try it but it doesn't work , i guess that it's due to the fact that get_object_taxonomies returns array of taxonomy and in other hand  $taxonomies variable in get_taxonomies_to_register is array of array so i guess i need  function who return array of array of my taxonomies.